# Sliding window algorithm for rainfall forecasting

Tags: algorithm, math

I am trying to implement sliding window algorithm for rainfall forecasting. The algorithm is follows:
[image: SWA]

This algorithm is from [An enhancement of sliding window algorithm for
rainfall forecasting in Zulikha, J. & N. H. Zakaria (Eds.)](http://icoci.cms.net.my/PROCEEDINGS/2017/Pdf_Version_Chap01e/PID29-23-28e.pdf)
I understand most of the steps except step 5 and 6. "The fifth step is compute the variation for selected minimum Euclidean distance, Edi and rename as mean variation previous (VP). Meanwhile, the variation of current year CY is also computed and rename as mean variation current (VC)."
What does it mean by compute the variation for selected minimum Euclidean distance? For the equation, V = AMt-AMt-1, I know that AM stands for average monthly. So current average month subtracts previous average monthly (december-november)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the equation is "average monthly at time **t**" minus "average monthly at time **t-1**" (previous month).

I suspect that "variation" is a translation error for "variance", the square of the standard deviation.